# serial port doesn't refresh received data until I restart the application

Tags: c#, serial-port

I wrote a message last week but would like to add another more simple question again to clarify.

I have a serial port console application. There are 20 virtual ports. My application successfully working but doesnt change received data value until I restart the application. I am not sure why it happens.

This issue appeared after FIFO enabled property was set to true.
How can i refresh serial port?

Thanks
--- here is the codes :

```
        static void serialportinstances()
    {
            for (int ix =1; ix < 20; ix++)
            {
                if (sportlar.ContainsValue("COM"+ix.ToString()) ==false)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SerialPort ekle = new SerialPort("COM" + ix.ToString(), 1200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                        //ekle.DtrEnable = true;
                        //ekle.RtsEnable = true;

                        try
                        {
                            ekle.NewLine = "\r";
                            ekle.Open();
                            ekle.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(datareceived);
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Dinamik SP {0} başarıyla açıldı", ekle.PortName));
                        }
                        catch (Exception eu)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Dynamic SP {0} açılamadı!", ekle.PortName));
                        }
                        sportlar.Add(ekle, "COM" + ix.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ee)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("port could not be created");
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

and datareceiving handler ;

```
        static void datareceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (mylockobject)
        {
            SerialPort spn = (SerialPort)sender;
            try
            {
                string s = spn.ReadLine();
                GetWeightPWI(spn.PortName, s);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error : " + ee.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

and parsing the received data here :

```
    private static void GetWeightPWI(string portadi, string alinan)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("PORT NAME : "+portadi+" and received data : "+alinan.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Are the 20 ports all connected at the same time?  Do the ports connect to 20 of the same device?  Do you have to query the devices to receive data?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: i added the codes into original message. Yes, all ports are virtual ports and connect to same device.this is a weightbridge console app and I can get weight values in real time while changing, there is no problem with that. but when format of the received data changes, serial port still shows the same and doesnt change. When i restart my application, serial port then shows the correct received data.

Comment: note : this problem appeared when FIFO was set to enabled mode. In the past, FIFO property was set to disabled and i had no issue like this.

Comment: I can't see anything here that is enabling a FIFO. Is there a reason you want this feature? I've never had an issue with serial ports when FIFO was untouched.

Comment: i just wanted to specify about FIFO issue. I am also not sure if this problem can be related to FIFO settings of ports. I only know that, this problem occured after fifo setting was changed.

Comment: The problem does not appear to be in your code (unless losing serial port handles is the problem). Try looking at your serial drivers. You do seem to be losing your serial port handles in that loop, consider storing your ports in an array so as not to lose any, C# might be closing them as you lose the handle.

Comment: I am not also sure if there is something wrong in the code. The problem is most probably in the driver settings. but a refresh command (that i dont know any command to reset the port) can resolve this problem. Because received data is correct when i restart the application. for example : i am getting following data : 1000,1000,1000,1000,.....(i enter tare button), 1000,1000,1000... same values are received and serial port still shows the same value. but must be 1000,1000,1000,.....(i enter tare button), 0-1000,0-1000,.... (received data format is changed)

Comment: there is no problem when i restart my application but fails if received data format changes again